# It is possible/make sense to add a mark to hide part of text?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, spoilers

In mathematics (and in other sciences), often there is no unique answer, the same problem can be resolved by different approaches, and often one can learn something from each one.

So in order to favour different approaches a nice way will be to add a spoiler like mark. Those that want the answer will just display it, but the ones that want to think they one approach will not.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-a-spoiler-tag-that-makes-hidden-until-you-click-text

Comment: ...and also [at gaming.SE](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/736/provide-a-markdown-extension-to-hide-text-anti-spoiler)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can now hide a portion of text with

```
>! Spoiler
>! text
```

It will be hidden until your mouse move on it, e.g.

> Spoiler
>    text

Comment: Nice! Does it work only for blockquotes?

Comment: @DumbCow: Yes .

Comment: Can you do one for me in the comments?

Comment: @DumbCow: No. Well maybe you could abuse $\color{white}{\text{white text in }\LaTeX}$.

Comment: @ParthKohli \color{white}{\text{white text in }\LaTeX}   - highlight his text to see what it says!